# JSon Column manipulation in PostGreSql

Tags: json, postgresql, properties, key, key-value

We are struggling with JSon column manipulation operations in PostgreSQL and can really use some help here. Please see the below example.

I have a "People" Table where properties are stored in JSon type column as Key Value Pair:

```
select "Propeties" from public."people"
```

Output:

```
[{"ClientId":"abc","ActiveStatus":1,Id:"123456"},{"ClientId":"XYZ","ActiveStatus":0,Id:"987654"},{"ClientId":"pqr","ActiveStatus":1,Id:"345679"}]
```

Problem 1:

On the above record I need to add a new Key called "Name " and Value as "Arjavi" of 1st indexno in the array where ClientId is "XYZ".  Expected output should look like this

OUTPUT:

```
[{"ClientId":"abc","ActiveStatus":1,Id:"123456"},{"ClientId":"XYZ","ActiveStatus":0,Id:"987654", Name:"Arjavi"},{"ClientId":"pqr","ActiveStatus":1,Id:"345679"}]
```

Problem 2:

I need to replace Key Name "ActiveStatus" with "IsActive" and Key Value =  0 where Id: "345679" and "ClientId": "pqr". Revised output would look as below:

OUTPUT

```
[{"ClientId":"abc","ActiveStatus":1,Id:"123456"},{"ClientId":"XYZ","ActiveStatus":0,Id:"987654", Name:"Arjavi"},{"ClientId":"pqr","isactive":0,Id:"345679"}]
```

Problem 3:

I want to remove the key called "Name" where key value is "Arjavi".

OUTPUT

```
[{"ClientId":"abc","ActiveStatus":1,Id:"123456"},{"ClientId":"XYZ","ActiveStatus":0,Id:"987654"},{"ClientId":"pqr","isactive":0,Id:"345679"}]
```

Problem 4:

We need to remove an Index in the array. (like "ClientId":"abc" has indexNO: 0, "ClientId":"XYZ" has indexNO: 1 ,"ClientId":"pqr" has indexNO:2)
so i want to remove the index no. 1 where "ClientId":"XYZ" and the o/p will look like

```
[{"ClientId":"abc","ActiveStatus":1,Id:"123456"},{"ClientId":"pqr","isactive":0,Id:"345679"}]
```

Any suggestions or solutions to help us move forward will be highly appreciated.

Comment: check this :
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/#:~:text=Querying%20JSON%20data&text=PostgreSQL%20returns%20a%20result%20set,JSON%20object%20field%20by%20text.

and this:

https://www.blendo.co/blog/storing-json-in-postgresql/

Comment: That's 4 questions in one post: this does not follow the guidelines on how to ask on Stack Overflow. Please ask just one question.